# Having trouble including python.h file

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, macos

Sorry for this silly question but i tried to test a model which said you can run it with python 3 but its written in python 2. The training code works but test code gives an error. so far i have edited python-config file but it gives me this error when i run test code:

```
./include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112:10: fatal error: 'python3 / Python.h'
      file not found
#include <python3 / Python.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

in common.h file, i read online that i need to edit it this way if i want to use python 3:

```
#include <python3 / Python.h>
#include <python3 / frameobject.h>
#include <python3 / pythread.h>
```

Sorry for this stupid question but I'm not able to do it with my project.

Comment: Editing c source files doesn't sound like something you should be doing to fix your python tests. What exactly are you trying to run?

Comment: I don't think there should be spaces in the `#include` path.

Comment: @sophros it doesn't

Comment: @RafalS I'm trying to run a text detection model. someone raised same error in the issues, its in chinese and i translated, I'm just trying to follow this because this way he got his problem solved. here's the link, translate last comment : [https://github.com/whai362/PSENet/issues/88]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a python3 folder with those header files in an enironment varaible.
The linker should then work and compile.
However: pybind should be as follows:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <frameobject.h>
#include <pythread.h>
```

Where you don't include any higher level folder.

I hope that helps!